# Does crouching/prone position improve accuracy?

Tags: day-of-defeat-source

Crouching and going prone further reduces recoil, the effect is most notable with the machine gunner and support classes. Unlike in other Valve games such as Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, the size of (dynamic) crosshair doesn't change when crouching (it does when the player is in motion) However, I don't know if accuracy is affected as **recoil doesn't equal accuracy** -- the first shot is obviously unaffected. Recoil also is less of a disadvantage when using semi-automatic weapons.

Comment: It is said on one class page on Wikia (http://dayofdefeat.wikia.com/wiki/Assault) that crouching increases accuracy, I don't consider this a reliable source.